# Number of days between two successive rows in pandas with timestamp ERROR: dtype('<m8[D]')

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a pandas dataframe like follows:

```
device_id   date
101        2018-10-30 10:42:32
101        2018-12-20 14:14:14
102        2018-09-26 14:21:33
102        2018-10-24 09:12:35
102        2018-11-12 04:52:21
```

My expected output is

```
device_id      date                  diff
    101        2018-10-30 10:42:32   0
    101        2018-12-20 14:14:14   51
    102        2018-09-26 14:21:33   0
    102        2018-10-24 09:12:35   28
    102        2018-11-12 04:52:21   19
```

I have used the following code:

```
df['exdate_1'] = df['date'].dt.date      
df['exdate_1'] = df.groupby('device_id')['exdate_1'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())    
df['diff'] = df.groupby('device_id')['exdate_1'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

but I am getting an error like the following

```
TypeError: ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') 
and dtype('<m8[D]')
```

What is wrong in my code? Can I use any other approach as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for datetimes without times, then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by multiple columns and for convert to days use your solution or alternative with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['exdate_1'] = df['date'].dt.floor('d') 
df = df.sort_values(['device_id','exdate_1'])
df['diff'] = df.groupby('device_id')['exdate_1'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   device_id                date   exdate_1  diff
0        101 2018-10-30 10:42:32 2018-10-30     0
1        101 2018-12-20 14:14:14 2018-12-20    51
2        102 2018-09-26 14:21:33 2018-09-26     0
3        102 2018-10-24 09:12:35 2018-10-24    28
4        102 2018-11-12 04:52:21 2018-11-12    19
```

Reason why get error is after `df.date` are returned `python date` object, and pandas working with it poorly.